# Erro "falha de segmentação" ao executar programa em C no shell linux

Tags: linux, memória, gcc

Tenho o seguinte programa na linguagem C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *p;
    char str[30], frase[]="Nome do arquivo :", resposta [80];
    int i;
    printf("Informe o nome do arquivo :\n");
    fgets(str ,20,p);
    for(i=0; str[i];i++)
    if(str[i]== ’\n’)
    str[i]=0;
    if (!(p=fopen(str ,"w"))){
      printf("Erro! Não é possível abrir o arquivo. \n");
      exit (1);
    }
    fputs(frase ,p);
    fputs(str ,p);
    fclose(p);
    p = fopen(str ,"r");
    fgets(resposta,atoi (argv[1]) ,p);
    printf("%s \n", resposta );
    fclose(p);
    return (0);
}
```

Estou compilando através do gcc do linux.
Já fiz várias alterações, aumentei o tamanho das listas de char e mesmo assim o erro "falha de segmentação" persiste logo no início da execução.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tem sentido você passar a variável `p` que vem do `FILE *p` para o `fgets()` se o intuito for pegar o input "digitado pelo usuário", o erro ocorre justamente porque a variável `p` não esta "manipulando" nada ainda, logo `fgets()` não entende o que "você quer fazer".

Se o intuito é pegar o "input" o certo seria ler o `stdin`, algo como:

```
printf("Informe o nome do arquivo :\n");
fgets(str ,20, stdin);
```

Mas creio que este não seja o seu único problema teu `for(i=0; str[i];i++)` está sem as chavetas `{...}`, creio que ele até executa a terceira linha de:

```
for(i=0; str[i];i++)
if(str[i]== ’\n’)
str[i]=0;
```

Mas qualquer erro ou mudança teu código vai quebrar e outra coisa, que pode ser do seu editor de textos, os apóstrofos parecem estar errados, se estiverem mesmo errados provavelmente vai receber:

```
error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers
if (str[i] == ’\n’)
              ^
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! Sabia que o problema seria nesta linha pq quando usei apenas o gets() funcionava, mas usando o fgets fica bem melhor.